# ORDER BY but make zeroes/nulls last by Adding minus in Order By in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to order by position on my query but set the zero to last. Here is the pseudo code

```
$this->db->select("id,position");
$this->db->order_by('-position', 'ASC' );
$result = $this->db->get( 'SampleTable' );
```

Codeigniter treats the query as

```
SELECT `id`,`position` FROM `TABLE` ORDER BY `-position` ASC thus having an error
```

Is there any way I can pass the **- minus** so that the query would be

```
SELECT `id`,`position` FROM `TABLE` ORDER BY -`position` ASC
```

Comment: -2,-1,0 you want this order right?

Comment: I just want to put the zeroes/nulls last. As I have seen in another question adding a - in the column (undocumented mysql query) that it does it however it doesnt work in CI due to the ` characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

```
        $this->db->select("id,position");
        $this->db->order_by('(position * -1)', 'ASC' );
        $result = $this->db->get( 'SampleTable' );
```